# Using mysqldump and database users

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to assemble all the options that I need for mysqldump to create everything used by my applications database into a single script.  This includes the database itself and all the database users/passwords/privileges.

I've got it all figured out with the exception of the user piece... here's what I'm currently using:

```
mysqldump -h host -u root -p \
    --add-drop-database --routines -B database_name > backup.sql
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: MySQL users aren't going to be stored in `database_name`.

Comment: I would like to link to [this solution in the DBA stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/mysql-show-grants-for-all-users/127529#127529).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The database users/passwords/privileges are kept in the `mysql` database, and won't get dumped with your dump command. You'll have to add that database as well to the list of DBs to dump:

```sh
mysqldump ... --routines --databases database_name mysql > backup.sql
```

or just dump everything:

```sh
mysqldump ... --routines --all-databases > backup.sql
```

Comment: Perfect - that's what I just found out.  I'd suggest that we just warn people that dumping/restoring the mysql db vs using the script I linked to could have some unintended effects esp. if the two servers aren't mirror images of each other (they don't have the same db's on them).

Comment: Remember that the mysql database has information in it about databases you may not be dumping. I don't know what will happen when you import that metadata into a new database server.

Comment: I actually wanted the opposite.  I wanted all "standard" the databases dumped, but NOT the user info etc.  So I used an explicit list of dbs, rather than all dbs to avoid dumping the "mysql" db.

Answer (score 33):

When dumping the mysql database, don't forget:

```
 --flush-privileges  Emit a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement after dumping the mysql
                     database.  This option should be used any time the dump
                     contains the mysql database and any other database that
                     depends on the data in the mysql database for proper
                     restore.
```

Answer (score 12):

So, I had a fundamental misunderstanding.  Users are not specific to a database, but are rather created at the server level.

You can view all existing users with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

Knowing this, it's pretty obvious that mysqldump shouldn't do anything with users.  However, if you need an answer to exporting/importing users and perms I suggest you check the following article - it helped me out.

http://pento.net/2009/03/12/backing-up-permissions-for-individual-databases/

My apologies for the noise on the board, but I figured I'd leave the post incase anyone else has the same misunderstanding.

Comment: Nope, this was just the thing to do. Additionally, if this post was what ACTUALLY let you solve it, then you should mark THIS ANSWER as "the answer" instead of the other one. Just thought I would share.

Comment: FYI the referenced link shows an SQL statement that gives an error with something like "Incorrect usage of UNION and INTO", the solution is to move the INTO to the last SELECT statement

Comment: Yep this is the answer. It answers AND you will need to use your brain a bit not just copy past some guy command

Answer (score 3):

Full process for me when migrating from one Mac OS X dev environment to a new one.

#### 0) Get rid of newer version of MySQL on new MacBook

I had accidentally installed MySQL 8, so I had to remove it because it was newer than my old MacBook.

```
# Remove binaries
$ brew uninstall mysql

# Remove data/config that is leftover
$ rm -r /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

#### 1) Install same version of MySQL on new MacBook

```
# Install version that matched old MacBook
$ brew install mysql@5.7

# Because it is an old version, you have to do a special configuration step
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile

# Start server
$ mysql.server start
```

#### 2) Dump data on old MacBook

```
$ mysqldump -uroot --flush-privileges --routines --all-databases > complete_dump.sql
```

#### 3) Restore data on new MacBook

```
$ mysql -p -uroot < complete_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [`mysqlpump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html), it can dump all databases, and can export the users as CREATE USER and GRANT statements instead of relying on the mysql system db + mysql_upgrade.

```
mysqlpump # Dumps (almost) all databases (see [2])
mysqlpump --exclude-databases=% --users # Dumps all user accounts
```

It's unclear from the docs if you can do `mysqlpump --users` and get both all databases and the users.

Some system tables get omitted by default, see [restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#mysqlpump-restrictions).

Comment: This is the only safe answer here. This is THE right answer.

Comment: In mysql 8.1: WARNING: mysqlpump is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use mysqldump instead.
I couldn't find a similar command in mysqldump options, any idea how we should proceed now ?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to your database server and execute:

```
select concat('show grants for ','\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') from mysql.user;
```

You'll get something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| concat('show grants for ','\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| show grants for 'mariadb.sys'@'localhost'              |
| show grants for 'mysql'@'localhost'                    |
| show grants for 'root'@'localhost'                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Capture the output to some temporary file.

And then cycle through each line in that temporary file, sending it against your mysql server, capturing the output.

Output will be something that you can use to reconstruct users on another server:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING 'invalid' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Here's a script I'm currently using:

```
mysql -u${BACKUP_DB_USER} -p${BACKUP_DB_PASSWORD} -e"select concat('show grants for ','\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') from mysql.user" > user_list_with_header.txt
sed '1d' user_list_with_header.txt > ./user.txt
while read user; do  mysql -u${BACKUP_DB_USER} -p${BACKUP_DB_PASSWORD} -e"$user" > user_grant.txt; echo "-- ${user}" >> user_privileges.txt; sed '1d' user_grant.txt >> user_privileges.txt; done < user.txt
echo "flush privileges" >> user_privileges.txt;
awk '{print $0";"}'  user_privileges.txt > all_user_privileges_final.sql
rm user.txt user_list_with_header.txt user_grant.txt user_privileges.txt
```

You'll have all grant statements in the file  `all_user_privileges_final.sql`.

Of course, you can limit your initial query to list only user(s) you want.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump version 10.19 contains the option `--system=users` wich adds *CREATE USER* with the *GRANT* commands into the dump.

```sh
mysqldump -h host -u root -p \
    --add-drop-database --routines -B database_name \
    --system=users > backup.sql
```

source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/

Comment: What is usable for older versions?

Comment: @Gábor can you elaborate, what situation do you have? I think you may install the new mariadb-dump and keep the old db.

Comment: how could I dump users on mysql 5 where --system is not available?

Comment: Unless I’m missing something this is only for MariaDB’s `mysqldump` version, not MySQL’s.

Comment: I looked at the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) and it seems its a mariadb function. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the option `--system=users` to get the user's dump from `mysql/MariaDB` if **mysql client is for MariaDB**.

For example:

1. check `mysql --version`. If output is like `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.8-MariaDB` then
2. `mysqldump -h <hostname> -u <usename>  -p --system=users >  mysqldb_users.sql`